# GLD Green Light Simulator not compiling

Tags: java, simulator

I found a traffic light simulator called Green Light District
the file I download included and explanation of how to build the project
and it says the following

> Extract the archive to a certain directory,
>   In that dir do `javac gld/*.java`
>   In that dir do `java gld.GLDSim`

I know * means all but...
first I want to know am I able to compile something like *.java
this is a link to the simulator , if some one can tell how to compile it , it would be really nice
[http://sourceforge.net/projects/stoplicht](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stoplicht/)/

Comment: Answer is found here *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801166/problems-with-compiling-a-simulatorjava*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs due to the fact that "enum" became reserved word in Java 1.5+, so it can no longer be used as a name for variables/methods/classes, but GLD uses enum as a name for some variables.

Once the name is changed - project will compile.

Alternatively one can try to compile it with compiler setting source version 1.4 - this should probably also work, but I suggest to simply rename all variables named enum.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all the code is in the folder called `gld`. You need to compile all the `.java` files inside it. After that, you run the main class `gld.GLDSim`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
You should use Java 1.4, this simulator is quite old, hence uses an old version of Java and some preserved words in more advanced Java versions.