# Problems with compiling a simulator(java)

Tags: java, compilation, simulator

I know it might be not the best place for this question but,am doing a master thesis on Smart Traffic controllers , I found this simulator which is written in java, it has been used in many papers I've read , but for some reason I can't/it wouldn't be compiled , anyone can tell me why ?
it can be found at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/stoplicht/

Comment: How do you compile the project and what kind of error do you get?

Comment: there is a text note describing how to compile it , but when I do , it keeps saying that some classes were not found , although I found them in folders

Comment: what tool are you using to extract. have you compiled java programs in packages before? need to keep the structure intact

Comment: am just using cmd command ... aint that right ?

Comment: gave detailed commands to run in cmd in my updated answer. i was able to build and run the tool.

Comment: do not use spaces in folder structures, use an _ if you must, they cause needless anxiety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was made with an old version of Java (pre 1.5)
It uses enum as a variable name. Need to as (javac tells you) give command :

> javac -source 1.4 gld/*.java

Note : when passing a path to Java both slashes work in Java

If your getting file not found your probably in the wrong folder.

Download a zip to a place lets say to folder:

> D:\prog\j\

Now open command prompt, I assume you have java bin JDK in windows PATH?

So now you have default source download zip

> gld_rel131_source.zip

in D:\prog\j\

Give following commands :

> D:
>
> cd D:\prog\j\
>
> mkdir traffic2\src
>
> cd traffic2\src
>
> jar xf D:\prog\j\gld_rel131_source.zip
>
> mkdir ..\bin
>
> javac -d ../bin -source 1.4 gld/*.java
>
> cd ..\bin
>
> java gld.GLDSim

Answer (score 0):

When you run `javac gld/*.java`, you get this kind of error:

```
./gld/algo/tlc/SL2TLC.java:272: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
(use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
            Enumeration enum = count.elements();
```

As specified in the error message, add `-source 1.4`:

```
javac -source 1.4 gld/*.java
```

And everything will be OK :)

You encounter this error because this project is old (2005), was written for J2SE 1.4 or former versions. `enum`, which used as a variable name in the project, is a keyword since J2SE 5.0. Thus, it cannot compile using newer versions, since its usage is reserved.

**EDIT**

Since your system is Windows, I would use a backslash (`\`) instead of a slash (`/`) for the path argument:

```
javac -source 1.4 gld\*.java
```

**EDIT 2** *Actually it looks like you were in the wrong directory (`gld/` instead of its parent). Simply `cd ..` and retry.*

Comment: actually when am doing "javac gld/*.java" I get this output...
javac: file not found: gld\*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
@ssssteffff

Comment: Are you using Windows @fadytaher ?

Comment: Try to run `javac gld\*.java` (using a backslash)